Mobile Safari is not rendering Flutter ShaderMask gradient color properly
I'm trying to implement gradientText in Flutter. Everything is cool except iOS Safari, which doesn't reflect gradient:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GradientText extends StatelessWidget {
  GradientText({
    required this.text,
    this.size = 20,
    super.key,
  });

  final String text;
  final double size;
  final colors = [
    const Color(0xFFC9BBE7),
    const Color(0xFFC2DCFF),
    const Color(0xFF75B1FF),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => LinearGradient(
        colors: colors,
      ).createShader(bounds),
      blendMode: BlendMode.srcATop,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: size,
          fontFamily: 'Satoshi',
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Here are the results:

The same from macOS Safari (Chrome and other browsers are ok as well)

As you see, the text under logo has no gradient for Safari.

Mobile web is using html renderer and for some reason ShaderMask is not working on html renderer.
Build your app with canvasKit renderer and it should fix your problem.
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
